# Cómo permitir que solo se puedan escribir números en el input

Tags: javascript

Me interesa que solo se puedan ingresar números en el input, intenté hacer algo con este ejemplo pero pues si no es *true* va a eliminar todo lo que se ha escrito...

```js
var a = document.querySelector(".number");

a.onkeypress = function() {

var i = parseInt(a.value);

var s = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

var e = s.indexOf(i);

if (e != -1) {

//

} else {

a.value = "";

}


}
```

Answer (score 4):

Podrías hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```html
<script>
function soloNumeros(e){
    var key = window.Event ? e.which : e.keyCode
    return (key >= 48 && key <= 57)
}
</script>

<table>
<td>
Edad:
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" id="age" name="age" onKeyPress="return soloNumeros(event)"/> 
</td>
```

Comment: Buena respuesta, pero no es recomendable el uso de [.keyCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) porque es una propiedad marcada como obsoleta y, seguramente, desaparezca en el futuro. Ahora se debe usar [.code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code), aunque puede ser un poco más complicado de trabajar, especialmente en casos como este.

Comment: Este metodo admite que pegemos texto, porque solo captura el evento `keypress`

Answer (score 4):

Puedes agregar un elemento a tu entrada `<input/>` llamada `type`, [referencia](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp), este lo que te permite es indicar que tipo de entrada quieres que sea tu textbox, en tu caso, lo que necesitas en que sea **number** por lo que quedaría mas o menos así

```
<input type="number" id="age" name="age"/>
```

Ojo, que la letra `e` si es considerada numero, ya que es un numero irracional llamada Euler.
Puedes tambien agregar rangos minimos y máximos

```
min="10" max="100"
```

Answer (score 0):

Puede usar el elemento de HTML "input" pero con el type = "number" ejemplo:

```
<input type="number" name="LoQueTuQuieras">
```

Comment: Como recomendación, trata de siempre verificar tus respuestas, por ejemplo el [*input type number*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/HTML5_input_types) acepta números decimales, por lo que en realidad no sería una respuesta correcta, podrías ajustarlo con min, máx y step. Te sugiero editar tu respuesta para incluir lo que menciono, como segundo comentario, es bueno agregar enlaces a documentación para que el autor pueda leerlo por su cuenta :)